# Continuity of separately convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, convex-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that it is convex in each variable (with all another fixed). Prove that $f$ is continuous.

Suppose $(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ are fixed. As a function of $x_1$, $f$ has left and right derivatives everywhere. I suspect these derivatives are actually equal (so $f$ is differentiable as a function of $x_1$). 
I don't think anything can be said in terms of second-order derivatives.

One probably has to prove that $f$ is continuous from first principles (mimicking the proof for usual convex functions).

Comment: It is not correct that $f$ has continuous derivatives, or even any derivatives. Consider for example $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R, x\mapsto|x|$.

Comment: What's the source of this problem ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon, Let $f$ is function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, such that it is convex by every variable (if all another fixed). Prove that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @GabrielRomon, last paragraht is my (not correct) trying.

Comment: @deadslug That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking where you found this exercise. Где вы нашли это задание?

Comment: @GabrielRomon it is a part of my homework (I can't do it myself)

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This proof is adapted from the proof of Theorem 2.31 in Dacorogna's *Direct Methods in the Calculus of Variations*. It is quite similar to the usual proof of continuity of convex functions.

---

Let $x_0\in \mathbb R^n$. Let us prove first that $f$ is bounded above in any neighborhood of $x_0$.
WLOG we may assume $x_0=0$. Consider $\epsilon >0$ and let $a=\max \{f(x),\; \forall i, x_i\in\{-\epsilon, \epsilon  \}\}$ be the maximum of $f$ over the vertices of the cube centered at $0$ with side length $2\epsilon$. Let us prove that $\|x\|_\infty \leq \epsilon \implies f(x)\leq a$.

Let $\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_{n-1}\in \{-\epsilon, \epsilon  \}^{n-1}$ be arbitrary. Separate convexity w.r.t $x_n$ yields $$\begin{aligned} 
\forall x_n \in [-\epsilon, \epsilon], f(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_{n-1}, x_n)
&\leq
\frac{\epsilon-x_n}{2\epsilon}f(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_{n-1}, -\epsilon)+
\frac{\epsilon+x_n}{2\epsilon}f(\epsilon,\ldots,\epsilon_{n-1}, \epsilon)\\
&\leq \frac{\epsilon-x_n}{2\epsilon}a + \frac{\epsilon+x_n}{2\epsilon} a \\
&=a 
\end{aligned}$$
For arbitrary $\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_{n-2}\in \{-\epsilon, \epsilon\}^{n-2}$ and any $x_{n} \in [-\epsilon, \epsilon]$, separate convexity w.r.t $x_{n-1}$ yields
$$\begin{aligned} 
\forall x_{n-1} \in [-\epsilon, \epsilon], f(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_{n-2}, x_{n-1}, x_n)
&\leq
\frac{\epsilon-x_{n-1}}{2\epsilon}f(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_{n-2}, -\epsilon, x_n)+
\frac{\epsilon+x_{n-1}}{2\epsilon}f(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_{n-2}, \epsilon, x_n)\\
&\leq \frac{\epsilon-x_{n-1}}{2\epsilon}a + \frac{\epsilon+x_{n-1}}{2\epsilon} a \\
&=a 
\end{aligned}$$
Iterating this process yields the claim.

---

Let us prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$. By the claim, there is some $a$ such that $\|x\|_\infty \leq 1 \implies f(x)\leq a$.
Let $\epsilon>0$. The upper bound $a$ can be chosen so that $\epsilon \leq an2^n$ holds. Set $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{an2^n}\leq 1$. Let us prove that $$\|x\|_\infty  \leq \delta \implies |f(x)-f(0)|\leq \epsilon$$
$\bullet$ Writing $x_1=\delta \frac{x_1} \delta + (1-\delta)0$ then $x_2=\delta \frac{x_2} \delta + (1-\delta)0$, etc... iteratively yields 
$$f(x)\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \delta (1-\delta)^{k-1}f(0,\ldots,0,\frac{x_k}\delta,x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n) + (1-\delta)^nf(0)$$
Since $\sum_{k=1}^n \delta (1-\delta)^{k-1} = 1-(1-\delta)^{n-1}$, one gets 
$$\begin{aligned}
f(x)-f(0)
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \delta (1-\delta)^{k-1} \left(f(0,\ldots,0,\frac{x_k}\delta,x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n) - f(0) \right)\\
&\leq a \sum_{k=1}^n \delta (1-\delta)^{k-1} \\
&\leq a \delta n \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}\\
&\leq \epsilon
\end{aligned}$$

$\bullet$ Writing $0=\frac{1}{1+\delta} x_1 + \frac{\delta}{1+\delta}\left(-\frac{x_1}\delta\right)$ then $0=\frac{1}{1+\delta} x_2 + \frac{\delta}{1+\delta}\left(-\frac{x_2}\delta\right)$, etc... iteratively yields 
$$f(0)\leq \frac{1}{(1+\delta)^n}f(x)+\delta \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(1+\delta)^k}f(x_1,\ldots,x_{k-1},-\frac{x_k}{\delta},0,\ldots,0)$$
and similarly 
$$f(x)-f(0)\geq -\delta (1+\delta)^n \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a}{(1+\delta)^k}\geq -an2^n\geq -\epsilon$$